# Preventing a google app engine module from starting automatically

Tags: google-app-engine, module

I have a default module that runs on the php google app engine.

I have a worker module that does tasks on behalf of this php module written in Python.

The python module is manually scaled, can only have one single instance, and kills itself with `modules.stop_version()` when it is done. It does not interact with humans.

The problem I am seeing with development and deployment on the development server is that each time I start my development server or make a change to my solution, this module will start and get it's /_ah/start even when technically it has nothing to do.

The php default module knows when and if the python worker needs to be started, and will do so with a:

    `$modules = new ModulesService;
    $modules->startVersion('worker','version');`

It also knows when not to start the worker, e.g. when it just quit because it already ran it's 8 allowed hours that day and should thus wait until the next day.

So there is no reason Google should ever start this worker module itself.

Is there a way to configure it this way? It would make used up quota measuring a whole lot easier.

Each time you start/stop you are billed 15 minutes according to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

> Instances running in manual and basic scaling modules are billed at hourly rates based on uptime. Billing begins when an instance starts and ends fifteen minutes after a manual instance shuts down or fifteen minutes after a basic instance has finished processing its last request.

Comment: what's your question? If you want total control, use manual scaling. And read the docs. Each backend instance is created in response to a start request, which is an empty GET request to /_ah/start. App Engine sends this special request to bring the instance into existence; users cannot send requests to /_ah/start. So you can't do anything about and it cannot serve further requests until that is sent.

Comment: I think the question is something like *"what is sending requests to /_ah/start and why?"* but the post seems to be mention only the development server.

Comment: @Paul I already use manual scaling, and my application starts running upon getting the /_ah/start call.
I can manually force the start call with the startVersion call so I don't need App Engine to send it at all, like after it killed the instance, or when I just uploaded it, when it's down, I like it to stay down until I wake it up again.

Comment: @tx802 as the google app engine is currently terminating this backend job with "Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 146 MB after servicing 2 requests total" I can't really tell how it is behaving after deployment for the time being.

Comment: then the "problem you are seeing" is not a problem at all, it's just the way it works. You say when you "make a change" or "when you start it" it sends the signal - it's doing what it's supposed to do! Also as you are now running out of memory after deployment it sounds like you may be better off with a managed VM rather then attempting to run what sounds like your normal application with few changes in the GAE cloud.

Comment: Given you can shut it down, as you say, once started, it seems your question is really "how do I save the billed 15 minutes when I upload a new version which is then automatically started". You might just consider enabling billing :P

Comment: Billing is enabled, but yeah, I was trying to save the 15 minutes of processing time. So far I haven't seen it rebooting intermittently, but as I had to implement `runtime.is_shutting_down()` checks all through the app, I was expecting it to go down often and auto restarting afterwards even when close to or past the daily free quota of 8 hours. A few good `del` instructions and a bit of juggling with buffer declarations do wonders on that memory by the way so that looks good too now. Not entirely convinced but as it is deployed and properly working now, the logs will tell just how bad it gets.